# Enforce TeX math font size

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, fractions

I want to stop the math size from automatically shrinking in math mode. Usually when, for example, having a lot of nested fractions, the size automatically shrinks to make it all fit.

But I want to prevent this. I want it to display in full size even when I have these nested fractions.

How is this possible?

Comment: Maybe, `\dfrac{}{}`?

Comment: your description is a bit misleading. the numerator of a fraction in texstyle is in scriptstyle but that happens even if there is only one fraction and no matter how much space is available, tex never automatically scales text "to fit",